# ViewPager+PhotoView

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Может быть, кто-нибудь может поделиться готовым классом, в котором совместно работают `ViewPager` и `PhotoView`?
P.s. слишком нагло?)

Comment: Есть, но там слишком много другого кода, от которого чистить слишком долго. Будет проще, если вы скажете в чём у вас проблема возникла при реализации.

Comment: Проблемы у меня нет. Я просто не знаю как реализовать все. Я думаю загрузить все картинки, сохранить их на sd-карту, сохранить в БД адреса картинок. При том я знаю, что есть адаптер ViewPager для фрагментов, и боюсь, что если я просто вставлю imageView во фрагмент, которые буду создавать динамически в ViewPager, то появятся проблемы.  В адаптере нужно переопределить метод getItem(int page), что я тоже пока не знаю как сделать.  И сохранять в БД мне нужно, потому что при попытке загрузить все сразу приложение вылетает, наверное не хватает выделенной приложению памяти. Все буду изучать.

Comment: Ну... У вас почти везде нерправильно запланирован процесс разработки. Хранить вам надо только список адресов картинок. Загружать/кэшировать/отображать картинки надо не руками, но либой типа `Glide`. Фрагменты вам не нужны. Вам нужен адаптер для `ViewPager` для обычных `View`. и обязательно надо очищать память, чтобы не было утечек + переполнения... Короче, вот можете мою реализацию посмотреть, но там сильно переусложнено относительно вашего варианта желаемого и много доп. либ используется для работы с разметкой, например.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mohaxspb/ScpFoundationCore/master/core/src/main/java/ru/kuchanov/scpcore/ui/adapter/ImagesPagerAdapter.java

Comment: Посмотрите в этой [статье](http://java-help.ru/android-photoview/)